# Can we create testng.xml file on a fly?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to create a UI which will show all the methods inside the project having @Test annotation. This will give the user an option to select the method which they want to execute during run time.

My intention is when user selects let say Method1 and Method3 from the UI, code should create a testng.xml file with Method1 and Method3 and pass that xml file for the execution.

Is there any way of doing this ? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: well a simple answer to that would be keep a testng.xml file ready as template and after accepting all the inputs from the user generate actual testng.xml file and pass that xml file to run after replacing the tokens in the template with the method names and other details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create TestNG at run time.

I have written utility to read all the test cases and and value designated by Y and N, depicting that if that test case has to be run or not. And the testng can be created accordingly. You can read values as selected from UI.

Below code can be of help to you:

```
public static void createTestNg() {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dbBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dbBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("suite");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            Attr rootNameAttribute = doc.createAttribute("name");
            rootNameAttribute.setValue("Suite");

            Attr rootParallelAttribute = doc.createAttribute("parallel");
            rootParallelAttribute.setValue("none");

            rootElement.setAttributeNode(rootNameAttribute);
            rootElement.setAttributeNode(rootParallelAttribute);

            Element testElement = doc.createElement("test");
            rootElement.appendChild(testElement);

            Attr testNameAttribute = doc.createAttribute("name");
            testNameAttribute.setValue("Test1");
            testElement.setAttributeNode(testNameAttribute);

            Element classesElement = doc.createElement("classes");
            testElement.appendChild(classesElement);

            Fillo fillo = new Fillo();
            Connection con = fillo.getConnection("./testCaseStatus.xls");

            String query = "Select * from Sheet1";
            Recordset recordSet = con.executeQuery(query);

            while (recordSet.next()) {
                if (recordSet.getField("Execute").equals("Y")) {
                    Element classElement = doc.createElement("class");  
                    Attr classNameAttribute = doc.createAttribute("name");
                    classNameAttribute.setValue(recordSet.getField("TestCase"));
                    classElement.setAttributeNode(classNameAttribute);
                    classesElement.appendChild(classElement);
                }
            }
            recordSet.close();
            con.close();
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                    .newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("./testNg.xml"));
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            // Output to console for testing
            StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
            transformer.transform(source, consoleResult);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FilloException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have used `fillo.jar` to read from excel. You can use any other utility as required.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll check the code and will share my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

`testng.xml` is not mandatory.

You can have your own implementation of [IMethodInterceptor](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors) where you will launch the GUI and then filter the methods you want.